# Twitter cards - Failed to get a proxied URL for the image

Tags: image, twitter, proxy, twitter-card

From time to time Twitter Card Validator shows an error for twitter:image:src - Failed to get a proxied URL for the image.

Domain is approved, robotx.txt is present in web root. Twitterbot successfully retrieves robots.txt, web page and image, but image is not shown in the Twitter Card.

Source page: http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/blog/how-to-create-great-content-for-your-business-blog/

Twit: https://twitter.com/mstzfort/status/363004775891087361

Metatags:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@BFMWeb">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/blog/how-to-create-great-content-for-your-business-blog/" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="How to Create Great Content for your Business Blog">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="In case you hadn&#8217;t already noticed, 2013 is all about content. Check out 7 content Ideas (+1 bonus) to help come up with great content for your business blog.">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Business-Blog-Content-197x110.jpg">
```

So, the question - how to show images in twitter cards?